# Problem with active status when an continue form have zero record for a filter

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

this is my first question here and english isnt my language but I'll try to explain at my best.
Im using MS Access 2007.
The form is a "continue form" with a header section where you find an "apply filter" button and a field named "cmpCercaCognome" (italian language for "find surname" plus "cmp" in italian language as field).

This is a cut out of the feature where I am having problems.
The function is fine if the search filter that is set in the field produces at least one result.
The function fails if there are no results.

```
Private Sub cmpCercaCognome_Change()

If (ActiveControl.Name = "cmpCercaCognome") Then
    LunghStr = Len(Me.cmpCercaCognome.Text)
    else
    LunghStr = Len(Me.cmpCercaCognome)
    End if

'Something else but I dont reach it

end sub
```

The error appear when I'm clicking in the field "cmpCercaCognome" and then Im typing a key there to change the value to use for a filter that I'll apply with a button.
The check "activecontrol" is true still the Len function give error "2185 - Cant read control... without an active status..). How? I just check that have active status! And Im typing just there...

I tryed to modify the IF check so:

"If (ActiveControl.Name = "cmpCercaCognome") And (Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount > 0) Then"

So I can check just when the count of the record is more than 0.
The problem that so I check the .value of the field that dont contain the last pressed key.
So isnt usefull for me

Is there any way to avoid the problem by keeping control of the temporary value of the field? Or is there a way to make the "temporary value" effective right away so as to avoid checking the .text property?
Thanks for any help you can get on this.

Comment: I would like to add that the "cmpCercaCognome" field is not linked to any field of the table or of a record, because a text must be entered manually to filter the surnames of the customers.
Also, each of the rows of the continuous form contains 6 fields each connected to the corresponding field of the customer database table.

Comment: I have never used Change event and never use ActiveControl. Why are you? Is cmpCercaCognome an UNBOUND control (not a field)?

Comment: Sorry, my bad translate ^^
"CmpSearchSurname" is a text box.
I use this text box to enter a word or a few letters to filter and reduce the lines in the customer table and find more easily what I'm looking for. Yes its unbound.

Comment: I'm using the "change" event because I have to act on other elements as I type the contents of the textbox.
For example, when the content is longer than one character, I change the aesthetics of the related column label. Or I change the background color of the textbox itself if you enter an invalid character.

Comment: If the form is filtered to show no records, and neither a new record can be created, all bound controls in the Details section "vanish", thus are not addressable.

Comment: And if I put the continue form in a sub form and leave the text boxes for the filters in the primary form? Teorically the primary form dont have more the problem of "no record" and can be always addressable?